# Adding Text to a Smalltalk Cell

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm doing a project in which I am adapting the Lights Out program in Pharo to a Minesweeper program, but I can't figure out how to add text to the cells so it shows up on-click like the color change does when it's "turned on". I've looked everywhere for a method for it with no dice.
Initialization method:

```
initialize
super initialize.
self label: ''.
self borderWidth: 4.
mineState := false.
cellValue := 0.
bounds := 0@0 corner: 32@32.
offColor := Color paleYellow.
onColor := Color paleBlue darker.
self useSquareCorners.
self turnOff
```

New Cell code:

```
newCellAt: i at: j
"Create a cell for position (i,j) and add it to my on-screen
representation at the appropriate screen position. Answer the new cell"
| c origin |
c := MFCell new.
"self labelString: 'hidden'."
origin := self innerBounds origin.
self addMorph: c.
c position: ((i - 1) * c width) @ ((j - 1) * c height) + origin.
c mouseAction: [self checkMineAt: i at: j].
^ c
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are approaching your issue in too complex manner.  You need to overload two selectors and you are done (not with the minesweeper, but the string on Cell).

I have taken the original code and just applied the label.

You have to just redefine `turnOn` and `turnOff`, which are in `SimpleSwitchMorph` which you are using, and apply a selector `label:` which can be found in super class `SimpleButtonMorph`.   You can even have the same logic as the in the superclass.

In `LOCell` you can do (create a new protocol `switching` for them):

```
turnOn
    super turnOn.
    self label: 'X'

turnOff
    super turnOff.
    self label: ''
```

When running the example now, the `X` String will be added to the cells that are turned on.

It will look like this:

The protocol:

[image: the protocol]

The morph now:

[image: the "morph"]